# Pass a different list types to method and loop through it like array

Tags: c#, linq, list, arraylist

// i have this class

```
    public class SCHOOL
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country{ get; set; }
        public decimal Total{ get; set; }
    }
```

// and another class with different type

```
    public class CLASS_2
    {            
        public string Student { get; set; }            
        public DateTime Graduate { get; set; }            
    }
```

// and may bee i add class 3 and 4 with different type

// i fill the lists with my data

```
  static void Main()
  {
    List < SCHOOL> FirstClass = new List < SCHOOL>();

    FirstClass.Add( new SCHOOL{ID=1,Name="aaa",County="USA",Total=10});
    FirstClass.Add( new SCHOOL{ID=1,Name="bbb",County="JAP",Total=7});
    FirstClass.Add( new SCHOOL{ID=1,Name="ccc",County="GBR",Total=5});


    List < CLASS_2 > SecondClass = new List < CLASS_2 >();

    SecondClass.Add( new CLASS_2 {Student =1, Graduate ="2/6/2015"});
    SecondClass.Add( new CLASS_2 {Student =1, Graduate ="2/4/2015"});
    SecondClass.Add( new CLASS_2 {Student =1, Graduate ="2/8/2015"});
  }
```

// i want to pass the first List and loop through my data

```
    GetmyData ( firstClass);
```

// and also pass another List with different Class type to the same method and also loop through my data
 
       `GetmyData ( SenecdClass );`

// i want one method to get the list and loop throught the data like array

```
private void GetmyData <T> ( List<T> newlist ) 
{

for (int y=0; y < newList.Count; y++)
{
     for ( int x=0 ; x < newLsit[y].Colms; x++ )
     {
         Console.WriteLine ( newList[y][x].value );
     }
}             
}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you're expecting this to do - the pseudo-code with poor formatting really doesn't help your cause. You *may* just be looking for using reflection to get properties - see `Type.GetProperties()` for example.

Comment: These code can't work, look `SecondClass.Add( new SCHOOL{` the `SecondClass` is `CLASS_2 ` and you cann't add here `SCHOOL`

Comment: Do you want to print the values of every property of every element within your list? So in case of `firstClass`-list you want to print the shools `ID`s, `Name`s, `County`s and `Total`s?

Comment: Please reformat your code sample(s). It is not just an inconvenience to potential readers, it could have the effect of driving them away. Formatting code matters, and posting badly formatted code sends a signal that the post is not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that firstly you need to use a generic method:

```
private void GetMyData(List<T> the List)
{
    foreach (T entry in theList)
    {
        //deal with the entry on the list
    }
}
```

and for the printing every property of the class, the best way in my eyes would be to override `ToString`

but if you need to access each property for something other than just displaying it will require reflection:

```
private void GetMyData(List<T> the List)
{
    foreach (T entry in theList)
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyName = property.Name;
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(entry);
            Console.WriteLine("Value of " + propertyName + " is " + propertyValue);
        }
    }
}
```

but bear in mind that not all properties can be read.

Comment: Sorry for the second class it must be  SecondClass .Add ( new CLASS_2 { Student =1, Graduate ="2/6/2015" }); .  i just want to loop through the 2D LIST<T> data and display its content whatever i passed different LIST<T> class to my method; and if there any way to loop like array of [row][col]

Comment: this is what i want , but can i make it to use the ( for loop )  instead of ( foreach )  .... is there any way to  get the propertyValue of the 
List  > for example  var Pvalue = property [ y ] [ x ].value

Comment: Thank you very much , after some trial and error i get to this, and it solved my proble

Answer (score 0):

static void GetMyData(List theList)
        {

```
        int count = typeof(T).GetProperties().Count();

        for ( int y = 0 ; y < theList.Count ; y++ )
        {  
            for ( int x = 0; x < count; x++ )
            {
                var propertyName = typeof(T).GetProperties()[x].Name;
                var propertyValue = typeof(T).GetProperties()[x].GetValue( theList[y] , null );
                var propertyType = typeof(T).GetProperties()[x].PropertyType;

                Console.WriteLine(propertyType + " " + propertyName +  " " + propertyValue );
            }                 
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is an obvious efficiency improvement to be made here, you call GetProperties `(3*count)+1` times when it could be called just once.